# generalized bayes rule?

Tags: probability, statistics

The Bayes Rule, as I learned, is given by:

$$P(\theta|X) \propto P(X|\Theta) \times P(\theta). $$

But I'm reading a paper, which applies Bayes rule in a weird way:

$$P(\theta|X,Y,Z) \propto P(X,Y|\Theta,Z) \times P(\theta|Z). $$

Does this generally hold? If so, where can I see a proof of that.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem  check out the "generalization"

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
P(\theta | X , Y , Z) &= \frac{P(\theta, X, Y, Z)}{P(X, Y, Z)}\\
\\
&= \frac{P(Z) P(\theta | Z) P(X, Y | \theta, Z)}{P(Z) P(X, Y | Z)}\\
\\
&= \frac{ P(\theta | Z) P(X, Y | \theta, Z)}{ P(X, Y | Z)}\\
\\
&\propto P(\theta | Z) P(X, Y | \theta, Z) 
\end{align*}